# AngularJS - Directive link function won't trigger after element is created from another directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm making a data form and part of it requires that it have a button to add another row of questions and another button to delete it's corresponding row. Hopefully I've just overlooked something and it's a simple fix, but if I have to reorganize any code I will. The problem I'm having is that when you click Add Stack it adds a new row of questions exactly like it's supposed to, but when you click Delete Stack nothing happens. From various methods of debugging I've found that the problem stems from the fact that the delete button is generated, and if I were to put a row that loads initially with the page it works just like it's supposed to. I would also like to point out that for the purposes of debugging the delete button just prints "test" to the console instead of actually deleting a row.

The relevant files are as following:

## app.js

```
/*global angular*/

var app;
app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'html/home.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http) {
    'use strict';

    $http.get('json/data.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    });

    $scope.change = function (item) {
        return item + '-changed';
    };
});

app.directive('removeStackButton', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.removeStack = function() {
                console.log("test");
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive('addStackButton', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.addStack = function() {
                $http.get('html/stack.html').then(function (response) {
                    var row = $compile(response.data)(scope);
                    element.parent().parent().prepend(row);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

---

## stack.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label for="stacks_totes">Totes:</label>
                <select name="stacks_totes[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label for="capped_stack">Cap:</label>
                <select name="capped_stack[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">No cap</option>
                    <option value="1">Cap w/o litter</option>
                    <option value="2">Cap w/ litter</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label for="cap_height">Cap height:</label>
                <select name="cap_height[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">(No cap)</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-sm ng-scope" remove-stack-button ng-click="removeStack()">Delete Stack</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

---

## home.html

```
<div>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Stacks</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-block" add-stack-button ng-click="addStack()">Add Stack</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery-2.1.4/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>


<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <ng-include src="'html/navbar.html'"></ng-include>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you saying `removeStack` doesn't get called? Cause it looks like it does get called

Comment: @user2341963 `removeStack` only doesn't gets called if the delete button is generated by the add stack button.

Comment: Seems to be working for me in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/US1KSJGmuFEIqaOsd2S6?p=preview). But you're better off changing your model to use an `ng-repeat` and let angular build the DOM for you

Comment: @user2341963 When I click any of the delete buttons in your plunker nothing happens.

Comment: Look at the console, `test` comes out which is exactly what your code is doing

Comment: @user2341963 The code doesn't work when I try it in my browser. Could the fact that your plunker doesn't put home.html in an `<ng-view></ng-view>` be affecting the results? And how do you suggest I use `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @user2341963 Sorry, I just tried it out and the problem definitively is not concerned by the use of `<ng-view></ng-view>`

Comment: @user2341963 Just took a closer look at your directive, thank you for the solution! I apologize, it was my understanding that you had copy/pasted my code into plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your comment of `ng-repeat`, you should create a model and work off that instead of the DOM. Chuck your stackForm into a directive. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6qqiTh8oumVZ15S7m8gR?p=preview) E.g.:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    // The stackList is your model. Work off this list instead.
    $scope.stackList = [];

    $scope.addStack = function() {
      $scope.stackList.push({});
    };

    $scope.removeStack = function(stack) {
      var stackIdx = $scope.stackList.indexOf(stack);
      if (stackIdx > -1) {
        $scope.stackList.splice(stackIdx, 1);
      }
    };
});
```

And in your markup:

```
  <button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="addStack()">Add Stack</button>
  ...
  <div data-ng-repeat="stack in stackList track by $index">
    <div data-stack="stack" data-remove-stack="removeStack(stack)"></div>
  </div>
```